# I have to change the url ?id= to / through web.config

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have to change the url through web.config from `all-products?id=Mw==` to `all-products/Mw==` for every page in site.

Please let me know.

Comment: You've tagged this as `.htaccess` but mention `web.config` in your question. What is the latter? What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^all\-products/([^/]+)$ /all\-products?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have to change the url ?id= to / through web.config file Please help me out

Comment: Do you main all-products?id=123 to all-products/123, if yes I updated